# Make C# function stored in XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a specific function that I want to run, and it is located inside an XML File:

```
Console.WriteLine("Text for test, {0}, {1}", testWord, testWord2);
```

The text is stored in an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <world>
    <region name="TestRegion">
      <area name="TestArea">
        <building name="Outside">
          <room name="TutorialRoom">
            <textToDisplay>"Text for test, {0},{1}"</textToDisplay>
            <extraString>testWord,tesWord2</extraString>
          </room>
        </building>
      </area>
    </region>
  </world>
</root>
```

I can easily get the string data using LINQ

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Load("..\\..\\LocationDatabase.xml");

        var textToDisplay= xelement.Elements("world")
            .Elements("region").Where(region => (string)region.Attribute("name") == "TestRegion")
            .Elements("area").Where(area => (string)area.Attribute("name") == "TestArea")
            .Elements("building").Where(building => (string)building.Attribute("name") == "Outside")
            .Elements("room").Where(room => (string)room.Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom")
            .Elements("textToDisplay");

        var extraString= xelement.Elements("world")
            .Elements("region").Where(region => (string)region.Attribute("name") == "TestRegion")
            .Elements("area").Where(area => (string)area.Attribute("name") == "TestArea")
            .Elements("building").Where(building => (string)building.Attribute("name") == "Outside")
            .Elements("room").Where(room => (string)room.Attribute("name") == "TutorialRoom")
            .Elements("extraString");
```

My issue here is how I make the command `Console.WriteLine("Something {0}", extra); to accept both LINQ statements. Anybody have an idea?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine((string)textToDisplay, ((string)extraString).Split(',')`? Please show the exact code you have, why it doesn't work, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply just pass in the strings as they are, however you will probably need to split the second one at the comma.

```
    string one = "format me {0}{1}";
    string two = "here, and here";
    Console.WriteLine(one, two.Split(','));
```

[IDEOne Example](https://ideone.com/K3wn4k)

Comment: That actually works??? I thought it would throw some error since two is essentially a string

Comment: Although OP hasn't explained it so well, my guess is that testWord and testWord2 are names of two functions that are defined in the code (and there are more such functions) and he needs to call them. Smells like Reflection.

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen -  You can see in the output of the example it is working fine for me (under the code window there is a stdout)

Comment: @dotNET - I hadn't considered that... I'll wait for OP's response

Comment: This actually blowed my mind. Thank you so much! (Yes this is what i wanted. I should have phrased it that the XML contains the ARGUEMENTS for the XML, and not a function itself)

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen - No worries

Answer (score 2):

The call to `Console.WriteLine()` is nothing special -- it just expects a `string` and an `object[]`. Your data is there, but buried in `XElement` instances. So

```
Console.WriteLine(
  (string) textToDisplay.First(), 
  ((string) extraString.First()).Split(',')
);
```

does what you want.

Note that this only works when "extraString" is something simple like a comma-separated list. You can't put arbitrary expressions like "2 + 2" in there and expect that to work -- for that we'd need to invoke the compiler and actually produce code, which is much more complicated.

Comment: The extraString will always have an ',' to separate the list. I am confused in why you used .First(), when the person above did not. Is there a specific reason why?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen: Yes -- it won't compile if you don't use `.First()`. Your statements return collections of elements. Depending on whether you have multiple `world` elements or just one, you may want to use either a `foreach` or an `XPath` expression to drill right down to the node you want.

Comment: Just one world element. It can have multiple region, area etc. For some reason, this doesn't support escape characters, such as \n. Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: @AhkamNihardeen: you can use `&#13;&#10;` in the XML to insert the linefeed as actual characters (but this is platform-specific). Otherwise, you can simply do a replace on the string to replace `\n` with `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: If I had this in XML: `Test word {0}\n{1}`
Should I replace it with: `Test word {0}Environment.NewLine{1}`

Comment: No, I mean `((string) textToReplace.First()).Replace(@"\n", Environment.NewLine)`. To prevent this comment train from going on too long, please open a new question or questions if you have more.

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

First split the extra string into a `String[]` by using `Split(',')` and then use a `String.Format()` to display the `textToDisplay` with the 2 strings in your string array.

```
 var values = extraString.FirstOrDefault().Value.Split(',');
 Console.WriteLine(String.Format(textToDisplay.First().Value, values[0], values[1]));
```

Comment: Your answer seems to one want to format properly ;)

Comment: I can't get the CSharp format right in this one ... don't know why - really

Comment: Neither to I. Maybe its confused at the var bit?

Comment: Think it was the list. Should look proper now.

Comment: Good :), Way easier to see